# Comparing Arrays and Create data into database

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I'm now stuck regarding array comparison and creating it. I have 2 tables, station and location. The columns inside station is the id and the station name. there goes the same to the location table only different is the name. I put the id into a array and the name to the array. I wanted to compare the name and the id so that when user select the name, the program knows which id belongs to the selected name and save it into the other table using their primary keys. Here were the codes that I created from now but I don't know how to solve it. Hope I could get some help here. Thanks!

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
        {
            string[] stations = StationNameList();
            int[] stationsID = StationIDList();
            string[] locations = LocationNameList();
            int[] locationsID = LocationIDList();

            int Stationindex = cbStation.SelectedIndex;
            int Locationindex = cbLocation.SelectedIndex;

            trolleyservice TS = new trolleyservice();
            TS.stationID = cbStation.SelectedIndex;
            TS.locationID = cbLocation.SelectedIndex;
            TS.tServiceTiming = txtTime.Text;
            TS.tServiceType = txtType.Text;
            Setupctx.trolleyservices.AddObject(TS);
            txtTime.Text = "";
            txtType.Text = "";

            MessageBox.Show("New Trolley Service Has Been Created.");
        }
    }
```

Here were all the arrays that I created for each tables.

```
 private string[] StationNameList()
    {
        using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
        {
            return Setupctx.stations.Select(s => s.Station1).OrderBy(s => s).ToArray();

        }
    }

    private int[] StationIDList()
    {
        using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
        {
            return Setupctx.stations.Select(sid => sid.idstations).OrderBy(sid => sid).ToArray();
        }
    }

    private string[] LocationNameList()
    {
        using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
        {
            return Setupctx.locations.Select(l => l.Location1).OrderBy(l => l).ToArray();
        }
    }

    private int[] LocationIDList()
    {
        using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
        {
            return Setupctx.locations.Select(lid => lid.idlocation).OrderBy(lid => lid).ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: When I select the station name, I need the station name to know it's ID and save into another table as I used the ID as the foreign key to that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can do thing, instead of taking two different array of name and id you can take list of station class like this.

```
 private List<stations> StationNameList()
  {
    using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
    {
        return Setupctx.stations.OrderBy(s => s.Station1).ToList();
    }
  }
```

now assign this list to cbStation as datasource like this

```
cbStation.DataSource =StationNameList() ;
cbStation.DataTextField = "Station1";//it is text field that you want to display
cbStation.DataValueField = "idstations";//it is value field of combo box
cbStation.DataBind();
```

Now use SelectedValue property of conbobox instead of SelectedIndex property you will get 
station id that related to station name.

```
 TS.stationID = cbStation.SelectedValue;
```

Same thing is for location also

you can also use array instead list here.